# Site redirecting to login page on every navigate action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, authorization

I've got an MVC app that's an API documentation site, sitting behind forms auth There are really only two pages in the site... home, which lists (at a high level) all the endpoints on the site, as well as the data objects. You can click on any one of these data objects/endpoints, and be taken to a details page.

Each of my pages are decorated with the `[Authorize(Roles="role,names,here")]` attribute. As expected, when you enter the site, you're redirected to the login page, and any subsequent requests simply work.

However, yesterday the site started acting up and I'm not sure why. After initial login, the page you requested loads just fine. However, any time you click a link to navigate to any of the other pages, users are redirected to the login page, and credentials no longer work.

Any thoughts as to what's caused this, and how I can fix it?

[Edit]
I don't know why, but my sessionState config was commented out in my web.config (I didn't do that, and as I said, this was working 48 hrs ago), but it appears uncommenting this fixed it:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="dbConn"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: Are you using the default Membership provider for the authentication or are you rolling your own?

Comment: Yeah sorry this is the default membership provider with mvc4 - so it's the Universal Providers.

Comment: After logging in can you check the response (using browser's debug tools) to see what the auth cookie expiration is set to?

Comment: In the Expires column for the Auth Cookie, it simply says "session". The other cookies have a datetime

Comment: If it is being treated as a Session, then the cookie would be removed when the browser is closed. However, like you mentioned, it is being removed on the second click. I would try setting the timeout property in authentication > forms section of web.config. It would be up to you if you want to also enable the SlidingExpiration

Comment: Timeout is already set to 2880. As I noted in my edit, my sessionProvider wasn't active - not sure what happened there - but it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

It was better to show us your class providing session.But use this:
you will have an account controller like this:

```
UserApplication userApp = new UserApplication();
SessionContext context = new SessionContext();
public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(User user)
        {
            var authenticatedUser = userApp.GetByUsernameAndPassword(user);//you get the user from your application and repository here
            if (authenticatedUser != null)
            {
                context.SetAuthenticationToken(authenticatedUser.UserId.ToString(),false, authenticatedUser);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

And your SessionContext will be like this:

```
 public class SessionContext
    {
        public void SetAuthenticationToken(string name, bool isPersistant, User userData)
        {
            string data = null;
            if (userData != null)
                data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(userData);

            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, name, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddYears(1), isPersistant, userData.UserId.ToString());

            string cookieData = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookieData)
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Expires = ticket.Expiration
            };

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }

        public User GetUserData()
        {
            User userData = null;

            try
            {
                HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
                if (cookie != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

                    userData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(ticket.UserData, typeof(User)) as User;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            return userData;
        }
    }
```